# Remove <tr> tags between two <tr> tags with a id pattern of a specified format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove all the `<tr>` tags between two `<tr>` tags with their id starting with this format `id="IT_BGJ_I_...."`
For example

```
<tr id="IT_BGJ_I_6262626_IW_7373737_IWL_4></tr>
<tr id="AB_C"></tr>
<tr id="AB_D"></tr>
<tr id="AB_R"></tr>
<tr id="IT_BGJ_I_434343_IW_4343434_IWL_4></tr>
<tr id="IT_BGJ_I_45456_IW_7373737_IWL_4></tr>
<tr id="AB_F"></tr>
<tr id="AB_G"></tr>
<tr id="AB_RE"></tr>
<tr id="IT_BGJ_I_443433_IW_4343434_IWL_4></tr>
```

I need to remove

```
  <tr id="AB_C"></tr>
    <tr id="AB_D"></tr>
    <tr id="AB_R"></tr>

<tr id="AB_F"></tr>
<tr id="AB_G"></tr>
<tr id="AB_RE"></tr>
```

from them.
The top and bottom  ids will be starting with the format `"IT_BGJ_I_....."`
using jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `^` jQuery selector which indicated `ID` or `Class` or any `attribute` that are start with.

```
$('tr:not([id^="IT_BGJ_I_"])').remove()
```

**OR**

As i can see you want to remove `DOM` which `id` is starting with `AB_`, so you can do this by

```
$('tr:[id^="AB_"])').remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`^` [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with 
a value beginning exactly with a given string.
```

code

```
$('tr:not([id^="IT_BGJ_I_"])').remove();
```

or

```
$('tr[id^="AB_"])').remove();
```

Comment: you have extra space between `tr` and `[` don't you think it will not select anything.?

Answer (score 1):

Or try `:not` :

```
$("tr:not([id^='IT_BGJ_I_'])").remove();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SawmJ/11/